# Json Array compare with different length in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below code which I am using for creating the new array if the id is the same in arr1 and arr2. But doesn't work since arr1 and arr2 are different. array 1 has index and arr2 is without index. screenshot for your reference. Can someone help?

Note: ID in arr1 is the same as EmpId in arr2

```
for(let i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
 merged.push({
 ...arr1[i], 
 ...(arr2.find((itmInner) => itmInner.id === arr1[i].id))}
 );
 }
 console.log(merged);
```

Array1 looks like this :

```
[{"Active":1,"Id":1},
 {"Active":1,"Id":3},
 {"Active":1,"Id":2}]
```

Array2 looks something like this:

[image]

Below is the sample code on how I am framing array 2:

```
renderElement(activity){
var arr2 = [] ;
for(var i = 0; i < activity.length; i++) {
obj = activity[i];
if(obj.Id == 28){
 fetch(geturl)
.then(function (response) {
return response.json();
})
.then(function (data) {
 res  = data;
 arr2.push(res)
})
}
else{
// Do nothing
}
}
return  arr2 
}
```

Calling Render method like below:

```
outputarray = currentComponent.renderElement(activity); 
console.log('output', outputarray)
```

Expected Output:

```
[{"Active":1,"Id":1,"Param1": true},
{"Active":1,"Id":3}, / Keep it as such if nothing exists in other array
{"Active":1,"Id":2, "Param2": false}]
```

Comment: Can you provide tangible sample array data? It would be clearer then to see how you are wanting to merge/join the two arrays.

Comment: I have added sample array and also the way i am framing arr2, can you please check now?

Comment: Do not push yur response to arr2 as it is created nested array, Instead directly assign it to arr2 variable.

Comment: I want to use this render method outside too,  thats the reason kept it as separate method. can you explain me on what exactly i should be doing here >

Comment: @Geethu can you show us what is your expected output based on the Array1 and Array2 values you have specified above?

Comment: Check this line: https://codepen.io/vicky86/pen/LYZdbNE?editors=0010
Line no. 11 I have made the changes.

Comment: I have added the expected output too. thank you all for your response.

Comment: renderElement function has only 1 purpose to get the response of Arr2. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Hi Vimal yes you are correct render is just to get the response of Arr2, I modified the way you suggested, in that case its giving me 0 output.                       outputarray = currentComponent.renderElement(activity);
 console.log('output', outputarray); / Gives me empty in this case

Comment: This way it will give you empty array. Because of async call. An the response you are getting is wrong. it is returing each object as a array.

Comment: Is there any way i can get rid of this? This is what i need since i will be using the outputarray when rendering and for other conditions too. can you suggest some?

Comment: Read this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach instead:

**Example #1**

```js
const arr1 = [
  { "Active":1, "Id":1 },
  { "Active":1, "Id":3 },
  { "Active":1, "Id":2 }
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    0: [
      {
        EmpId1: 1, Param1: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    1: [
      {
        EmpId2: 2,Param2: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    2: [
      {
        EmpId3: 2
      }
    ]
  },
];


const response = arr1
  .reduce((acc, value) => {
    const secondaryData = arr2.map((val, index) => {
      const { [`EmpId${index + 1}`]: Id, ...others } = val[Object.keys(val)][0];
      return { Id, ...others };
    });

    const match = secondaryData.findIndex(({ Id }) => Id === value.Id);
    
    if (match >= 0) acc.push({...value, ...secondaryData[match]})
    else acc.push(value);

    return acc;
  }, []);


console.log(response);
```

**Example #2**

```js
const arr1 = [
  { "Active":1, "Id":1 },
  { "Active":1, "Id":3 },
  { "Active":1, "Id":2 }
];

const arr2 = [
  [
    {
      EmpId1: 1, 
      Param1: true
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      EmpId2: 2, 
      Param2: false
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      EmpId3: 2
    }
  ],
]

const response = arr1
  .reduce((acc, value) => {
    const secondaryData = arr2.map(([val], index) => {
      const { [`EmpId${index + 1}`]: Id, ...others } = val;
      return { Id, ...others };
    });
    
    const match = secondaryData.findIndex(({ Id }) => Id === value.Id);

    if (match >= 0) acc.push({...value, ...secondaryData[match]})
    else acc.push(value);

    return acc;
  }, []);


console.log(response);
```

Comment: Hi Kshewengger, this didnt work.. i am still getting Arr1 without being merged :-(

Comment: Hi @Geethu, I have updated the snippet to conform with your latest change on your arr2 values. If you'll run the snippet above, you can see that the arr1 and arr2 are merged. May I know if I have missed something?

Comment: Thank you much for your time, i am still a beginner. sorry for the confusion i found why its not working for me. Can you please suggest something for the modified arr2? this is how it is thats the reason, its not working.

Comment: Hi @Geethu, no problem. On your modified arr2, it's actually an invalid format, which you can confirm by pasting it in your console or editor. Do you perhaps meant it like this? Example on the 1st item where instead of array after the object, it's corresponding has an index in it?

const arr2 = [ {  0: [ { EmpId1: 1, Param1: true } ] } ];

or may I know if it's different. You may need to edit your arr2 to it's valid format :)

Comment: I have added a screenshot , not sure if that helps... it looks like const arr2 = [0:[ { 0: [ { EmpId1: 1, Param1: true } ] } ];

Comment: Hi @Geethu, I have updated the snippet above with the updated arr2 value. May I know if this works on your side? just run the snippet and see if all is well :)

Comment: I have added a 2nd example based on what I have understood on your screenshot based on your data. May I know if it works on your side :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can create a hash map by a object property and join on that property all the arrays, i.e. reduce an array of arrays into a result object, then convert the object's values back to an array. Since each array is reduced this means each array is only traversed once `O(n)` and the map object provides constant time `O(1)` lookup to match objects. This keeps the solution closer to `O(n)` rather than other solutions with a nested `O(n)` `findIndex` search, which yields a solution closer to `O(n^2)`.

```
const mergeByField = (...arrays) => {
  return Object.values(
    arrays.reduce(
      (result, { data, field }) => ({
        ...data.flat().reduce(
          (obj, el) => ({
            ...obj,
            [el[field]]: {
              ...obj[el[field]],
              ...el
            }
          }),
          result
        )
      }),
      {}
    )
  );
};
```

Load each array into a payload object that specifies the field key to match on. This will return all fields used to match by, but these can safely be ignored later, or removed, whatever you need. Example:

```
mergeByField(
  { data: arr1, field: "Id" },
  { data: arr2, field: "EmpId" },
);
```

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    Active: 1,
    Id: 1
  },
  {
    Active: 1,
    Id: 2
  },
  {
    Active: 1,
    Id: 3
  }
];

const arr2 = [[{ EmpId: 1, Param1: true }], [{ EmpId: 3, Param2: false }]];

const mergeByField = (...arrays) => {
  return Object.values(
    arrays.reduce(
      (result, { data, field }) => ({
        ...data.flat().reduce(
          (obj, el) => ({
            ...obj,
            [el[field]]: {
              ...obj[el[field]],
              ...el
            }
          }),
          result
        )
      }),
      {}
    )
  );
};

console.log(
  mergeByField({ data: arr1, field: "Id" }, { data: arr2, field: "EmpId" })
);
```

Comment: Hi Drew Reese, thank you for your response. Let me give a try

Comment: Updated to fix dropping properties.

Comment: Thank you for explaining me, but in my case 'ID' in arr1 is same as 'EmpId' in arr2

Comment: @Geethu Please check generalized solution. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, i am still a beginner. i found why its not working for me. Can you please suggest something for the modified arr2? this is how it is thats the reason, its not working.

Comment: Sorry for this confusion, still a learner. just noticed that array2 is of different format when pushing with renderElement method.

Comment: @Geethu Are you sure that is your `arr2` shape? It isn't valid; each object of the outer array needs a key.

Comment: If you check my RenderElement method, that is how i am framing arr2. Is there a way i can share my screen?

Comment: @Geethu I copy pasted your `arr2` snippet into an IDE to format it so I could better read it and it isn't valid, it won't format. You can try creating a simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that repros your issue and share here.

Comment: @Geethu Your `arr2` is an array of arrays where each array element holds a single object, i.e. `[[{...}], [{...}], ...]`. My solution has an `arr2` with such a shape as you had posted earlier. I call `.flat()` on it to flatten it back to an array of just the objects.

Comment: Tried, but its returning me only 1 of the row from master array without merge. i am not sure about the reason

Comment: @Geethu If you could provide a *runnable* example of your code we could better help debug. Try creating a *running* codesandbox of your component.